# How to get the default value of an object property?

Tags: c#, default, propertyinfo

Some code:

```
foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo pi in myObject.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    if (pi.CanWrite)
    {
        object value = pi.GetValue(Properties, null);

        // if (value is not default)
        // {
        X.addAttribute(pi.Name, value);
        // }
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is not-call the line 'X.addAttribute...' if the property is at its DefaultValue. I assume there's some way of getting the DefaultValue of a property so I can do a comparison?

For my purpose I am trying to get the 'default' value as defined by DefaultValueAttribute.

Any help is appreciated, cheers.

Comment: Answers will depend based on how you define "default value". The two obvious definitions are CLR-Default (`null` for reference types, 0 for value types) or the `DefaultValueAttribute`. Can you edit your question to clarify which you are interested in?

Comment: Hi, apologies; I should have specified. It was default as defined via DefaultValueAttribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to get the DefaultValue attribute, use `GetCustomAttributes` on your `PropertyInfo` objects.

Comment: Cheers. This is the bit of info I needed for my purpose.

Answer (score 5):

Below is the method I use to get a default value of any **runtime-type** it will return 'null' for non value types otherwise it will return the default value type (it includes caching of value types for extra perf):

```
private static readonly Dictionary<Type, object> DefaultValueTypes 
    = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

public static object GetDefaultValue(Type type)
{
    if (!type.IsValueType) return null;

    object defaultValue;
    lock (DefaultValueTypes)
    {
        if (!DefaultValueTypes.TryGetValue(type, out defaultValue))
        {
            defaultValue = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            DefaultValueTypes[type] = defaultValue;
        }
    } 

    return defaultValue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but my system uses some non-value types. This is a handy bit of code to have anyway :).

Comment: Alternatively, if the type is known at compile-time, the `default` keyword can be used.

Answer (score -3):

First, You must always initialize the field with value you want as a default.

Something similar

```
    class UnitManager
    {
      private int value;

      [DefaultValue("0")]
      public int Value
      {
       get { return this.value; }
       set { this.value = value; } 
      }
    }
```

Then simply use

```
    UnitManager manager = new UnitManager()

    int startValue = manager.Value;
```