# Getting and setting defalut property value in c#

Tags: c#, class, object, properties, get

```
class Log
{
 public int LocationId { set { value = 1; } get; }
}
```

> Will this set the default value for Log as 1 when i use like this: Log
>   l=new log(); Console.Writeline(l.LocationId);
>
> ?

I am aware of the normal way of using a property but will this also work?

Comment: > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40730/how-do-you-give-a-c-sharp-auto-property-a-default-value
> 
> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272469/how-to-get-the-default-value-of-an-object-property

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proper way to do it is in the constructor:

```
class Log {
    public Log() {
        LocationId = 1;
    }

    public int LocationId { set; get; }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

No, you should do like this:

```
class Log
{
   private int locationID = 1; //This is a default value
   public int LocationId 
   { 
      set 
      { 
          locationID = value; 
      } 
      get 
      {
          return locationID;
      } 
   }
}
```